# Message field is becoming empty when clicking submit

Tags: php, html, validation, phpmailer

I have combined PHP validation and PHPmailer, the code is working perfectly.
The only problem I am facing now is whenever I click submit, the message "textarea" is getting empty, therefore I have to retype the whole message again.
Example: if the name is wrongly entered and all other fields are OK, when you click submit it will show the warning message under the name field but the message will be coming empty, I hope I have delivered my message in a proper way.
*I am using PHPmailer without composer.

**index.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Event Axis</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php include('contact.php');?>
            <form id="contact" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                <fieldset>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" type="text" name="name" value="<?= $name ?>" tabindex="1">
                    <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" 
                        name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="2">
                    <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number, ex: 1122334455" type="text" name="phone" value="<?= $phone ?>" tabindex="3">
                    <span class="error"><?= $phone_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message here" type="text" name="message" value="<?= $message ?>" tabindex="5"></textarea>
                    <span class="error"><?= $message_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="Sending.." value="">Submit</button>
                    <span class="success"><?= $success; ?></span>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**contact.php**:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; //You shall use the following exact namespaces no matter in whathever directory you upload your phpmailer files
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = $phone_error = $message_error = "";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = $success = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if(empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $name_error = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
            $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if(empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email_error = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email_error = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if(empty($_POST["phone"])) {
        $phone_error = "Phone is required";
    } else {
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,10}$/", $phone)) {
            //if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)){
            $phone_error = "Invalid phone number";
        }
    }

    if(empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message_error = "Message Can Not Be Empty";
    } else {
        $message = ($_POST["message"]);
        //$message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
        //$message = "$message";
    }

    //if all the errors are empty, only then send the message
    if($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $message_error == '') {
        $message_body = '';
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $message_body .= "$key: $value\n";
        }

        require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
        require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
        require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // Passing `true` enables exceptions

        try {
            //Server settings
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'mail.ogero.gov.lb'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            //$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
            //$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
            //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 25; // TCP port to connect to

            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
            $mail->addAddress('mozes_86@hotmail.com', 'Joe User'); // Add a recipient
            //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
            $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
            $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
            $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

            //Attachments
            //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
            //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

            //Content
            $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
            $mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

            $mail->send();
            //echo 'Message has been sent';
            $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
            //reset form values to empty strings
            $name = $email = $phone = $message = '';
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }
}

function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use     `echo` to show the value in the textarea.
Then do not use     `value=" "` , instead use the textarea's value in the between the textarea tags

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `input`, the `textarea` tag has no `value` attribute, its text is directly written between the opening and closing tag:

```
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message here" type="text" name="message" tabindex="5"><?= $message ?></textarea>
```